# How to use multiline command in 'script:' with YAML?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, yaml, travis-ci

I have a repository that uses `Travis CI`, and in the `.travis.yml` there I have this line:

```
script:
- vim -Nu <(cat <<-EOF
  set nocompatible |
  filetype off
  EOF
  ) -c 'Script' > /dev/null
```

Sadly this doesn't work, as this is transformed into a single line and is executed like this:

```
vim -Nu <(cat <<-EOF set no compatible | filetype off | EOF ) -c 'Script' > /dev/null
```

This makes the `EOF` tag not working, as `EOF` needs to be in a single line.
An alternative would be to just use normal quotes like this:

```
script:
- vim -Nu <(cat 'set nocompatible |
  filetype off
  ) -c 'Script' > /dev/null
```

Which works, and is fine, but I feel there must be a way to insert newlines into a `.travis.yml`. I have an alternative now, but I may not in the future. So how do you do it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In YAML you can specify newlines in a scalar by using `""` quoting and escaping the newlines (`\n`), or, and that is more natural for your case, by using a [literal style block scalar](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688):

```
script:
- |
  vim -Nu <(cat <<-EOF
  set nocompatible |
  filetype off
  EOF
  ) -c 'Script' > /dev/null
```

This is a scalar starting with a line with a `|` (pipe symbol), followed by multiple lines for which the line-breaks are preserved.

- The lines are normally indented (exception: a single top-level literal style block scalar).
- After the `|` there can be modifiers: `1`-`9`, used when your first line starts with spaces; `+`, `-` to influence stripping of final newlines (normally collapsed into one).

Answer (score 64):

Your question relates to the [YAML language standard](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/), which is used in the configuration files of many CI/CD systems, including Travis CI, GitLab CI, GitHub Actions, and others. However, it's worth noting that not all CI/CD systems support the YAML standard fully, and they might also add their own extensions.

YAML has special block styles for handling line breaks. In your case, the [folded block style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251),  denoted by the “`>`” symbol might be useful. It allows long lines to be broken up for readability while retaining the semantics of the original long line. Here's an example:

```
script:
    - >
      valgrind
      --read-var-info=yes
      --error-exitcode=1
      --fullpath-after=
      --track-origins=yes
      --leak-check=full
      --num-callers=20
      --suppressions=$(pwd)/tests/zephir_parser.3.7.0.sup
      $(phpenv which php)
          -d variables_order=EGPCS
          run-tests.php
              -p $(which php)
              -d extension=$(pwd)/modules/zephir_parser.so
              -d variables_order=EGPCS
              -g "FAIL,XFAIL,BORK,WARN,LEAK,SKIP"
              --offline
              --show-diff
              --set-timeout 120
```

In this style, each line break is replaced with a space. Indentation in each line will be ignored. A line break will be inserted at the end.

**Note:** The backslash “`\`” must not be used here, as it will be treated as a line continuation. Thus, *the following example is wrong*:

```
script:
    - >
      valgrind \               # this line wrong
      --read-var-info=yes
```

Otherwise it will be treated as `valgrind \ --read-var-info=yes`.

However, it's important to note that different CI/CD systems may have their peculiarities in processing configuration files. For instance, [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) uses a [line folding](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048) style (“`>-`”), which allows long lines to be placed on multiple lines, but processes them as a single line. Here's an example:

```
  - name: Configure (x64 Debug)
    run: >-
      cmake
      -S .
      -Bbuild
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
      -DCPPCHECK=ON
      -DWARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=ON
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/my-program
      -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

In this case, after processing, all lines are concatenated into one.

**Note:** With line folding lines are left aligned, using *the same indentation* at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Can you throw a pipe in the middle of this? Or would that be bad?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah YAML doesn't interpret the contents of the scalar beyond  the newline after the first pipe, everything else is take "as is" (until you dedent).

Comment: I use ``\`` as usual, and it breaks. Why isn't ``\`` required in this case?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Updated reply

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is `|`. Here is a very clear example to refer to.

```sh
   build:
     commands:
       - echo "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN}"
       - |
         if expr "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN}" : ".*build/MyProjectDev-" >/dev/null; then
           yarn run build-dev;
         fi
       - |
         if expr "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN}" : ".*build/MyProject-" >/dev/null; then
           yarn run build-prod;
         fi
```

Comment: This seems to repeat other answers, but thanks for showing how to use this syntax in a larger context, it's quite helpful.