# CAT EOF generated in a single line fail to run

Tags: unix, yaml, eof, cat

I have a yaml file where I want to write a XML:

```
  script:
    - >
      cat > settings.xml << EOF
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <servers>
      <server>
      <username>$USERNAME</username>
      <password>$PASSWORD</password>
      <id>central</id>
      </server>      
      </servers>
      </settings>
      EOF
```

If I run the cat command in my terminal, it works but when it's executed by my pipeline, this command become a single line failing:

```
cat > settings.xml << EOF <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <servers> <server> <username>$USER</username> <password>$PASSWORD</password> <id>central</id> </server> </servers> </settings> EOF
```

With the error:

```
parse error near `<'
```

Any idea how to fix this error or generate a well formated XML?

Comment: try `cat  << EOF > settings.xml`

Comment: Same error with this syntax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745696/how-to-use-multiline-command-in-script-with-yaml

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. Incorrect syntax (incorrect `cat > settings.xml << EOF` instead of correct `cat << EOF > settings.xml`)
2. The end-string `EOF` must be at the beginning of the line but it isn't.

To run this from the command line:

1. Type `cat << EOF > settings.xml` and press `ENTER`.
2. Paste (or type by hand) your XML document (without the end-string `EOF`) and press `ENTER`.
3. Type `EOF` (make sure it is at the beginning of the line!) and press `ENTER`.

You will be presented with the command prompt. Type `ls -l settings.xml` to see the newly created file.

To run this from a script:

Open your text editor and follow the steps 1, 2 and 3.

Save it under the name, lets say `script.sh` and make it executable:

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

Run it:

```
./script.sh
```

When the command promt is back, type `ls -l settings.xml`, to see the newly created file.