# How to run a bash script in a AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to install MongoDB from a script in a EC2 from AWS CloudFormation. I want the script to automatically run when the stack is created from the template.

On line 303 of [this template](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-mongodb/blob/main/templates/mongodb-node.template.yaml) by Amazon you can see they do this

However, I am confused on the use of the backslash at every line. What format is needed to put a bash script into a AWS template so it runs on startup?

Comment: @Marcin actually ive beens struggling. I am starting simple with [this](https://ibb.co/rpgdkDt) and its saying "Invalid template property or properties [Properties]"

Comment: Please make new question for the new issue.

Comment: @Marcin No problem. I have made a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508353/aws-cloudformation-template-not-accepting-bash-script). Please check it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) and in CloudFormation (CFN) it can be specified in multiple ways. The template in the link also use [cfn-ini](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) thus it has those "backslash". They are used to **split a single line into multiple lines** for readability.

Often the following form of user-data is enough which is easier to write and read:

```
      UserData: !Base64
        Fn::Sub: |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo "first command in bash"
          echo "second command in bash"
          echo "and so on ..."
```

Comment: Can you show a complete example of substitution within CloudFormation? This is actually hard as it seems to expect type "string."

Answer (score 3):

In General, if you have a very long single line bash command you can split it into multiple lines using a `\` for ease of reading.
Please refer [this](https://superuser.com/questions/508507/linux-bash-script-single-command-but-multiple-lines) StackExchange link.  The AWS Cloudformation template referred in the question uses similar concept. Since it was a single line command, they have made it **multiline for readability**.

For reader's information, if you are using CloudFormation/YAML and you have a **multi-line** **in-line** bash/python script you can refer the `|` operator [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070155/in-cloudformation-yaml-use-a-ref-in-a-multiline-string-use-fnsub) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745696/how-to-use-multiline-command-in-script-with-yaml/68669931#68669931)