# AWS CloudFormation template not accepting bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Trying to put a bash script to install MongoDB on an EC2 via userdata. Im starting simple with [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/mongodb+ubuntu+20.04+install+script) easy script before I do that one I am actually trying to do. I cannot even get the simple one to work. When I try and create the stack with the template below it gives me the error **Invalid template property or properties [Properties]**. Any ideas whats wrong with my userdata section?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Launch EC2 via CloudFormation 

Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: mongodb
    
  AvailabilityZone:
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
    
  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16

  PublicSubnetCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24

  PrivateSubnetCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24
    
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

Resources:
  496Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-04505e74c0741db8d # ImageID valid only in us-east-1 region
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref 496SecurityGroup

  496SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [496-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      
  PublicSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnetCIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnetCIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
          
  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
 
  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DefaultPrivateRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway

  NatGatewayEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet

Properties:
  UserData: !Base64
    Fn::Sub: |
        #!/bin/bash
        wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
        echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserData` is [part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) of `AWS::EC2::Instance`. It is not a separate resource. Thus it should be:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Launch EC2 via CloudFormation 

Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: mongodb
    
  AvailabilityZone:
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
    
  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16

  PublicSubnetCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24

  PrivateSubnetCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24
    
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

Resources:
  496Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-04505e74c0741db8d # ImageID valid only in us-east-1 region
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref 496SecurityGroup
      UserData: !Base64
        Fn::Sub: |
            #!/bin/bash
            wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
            echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org        

  496SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [496-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      
  PublicSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnetCIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnetCIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
          
  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
 
  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DefaultPrivateRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway

  NatGatewayEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
```

Comment: thank you. I see my mistake now. I appreciate your response. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Crunchy No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: That MongoDB script did work great! I tested it all went well. However, running into a small issue trying my own script now. does the bash script need to not have any indents? I have many indents throughout my script and I think its causing problems. @Marcin

Comment: @Crunchy No, it seems fine. You can check logs in  `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and
`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the instance.